# Custom user profile property in SPO (SharePoint online) UPA gets changed next day

Tags: sharepoint-online, user-profile, user-profile-service

We have a custom user profile property in SPO (SharePoint online) of Boolean type (check box). We are updating this property to true (Checked) using PowerShell script but when we check it next day, that property is set to false (unchecked) again. Any suggestion what could be the reason?

Comment: Does the property mirror a property that exists in Azure AD?

Comment: No. It is custom property populated through PowerShell script.

Comment: You may need to talk to Microsoft support.

Comment: I got the reason. There was on custom PowerShell script which was resetting it.